# Tableau filters

Tags: tableau-api, desktop

I have my sub category in rows and sum(sales) in columns. If a apply a filter with product name, my sub category and sum(sales) chart should not change. The filter should not effect my chart. Data source I am using is sample superstore.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: If you are applying a filter how/why will it not affect your chart. Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish by applying the product name filter?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect assumption. Every Product fits somewhere into a sub-category. Prove this by putting Sub-Category on columns and Product Name on Rows. Therefore, if you filter out one or more products, the associated bar chart will be modified where the product name(s) you remove will have corresponding changes in the associated sub-category.